# Facebook Account Kit in Ionic/Cordova app

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to connect Facbook Account Kit in Ionic/cordova App, main problem i faced that in facebook account kit set client/server side domain name but in ionic/cordova app the webview serve from file system("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/app/request"). So how to do this in Ionic app.

Comment: have a look at this https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/

Comment: brother its facebook account kit not login on facebook .https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugin instead of webview https://github.com/gurisko/cordova-plugin-accountkit

Steps:

1. Create a Facebook application from https://developers.facebook.com
2. Enable Accountkit; Copy required credentials
3. Add AccountKit plugin

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-accountkit --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication" --variable CLIENT_TOKEN="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

```js
AccountKitPlugin.loginWithPhoneNumber({
    useAccessToken: true,
    defaultCountryCode: "US",
  },function(res){
    console.log(res)
  },function(err){
     console.log(err)
})
```

Incase of Ionic with typescript just add (window) before function

```js
(<any>window).AccountKitPlugin.loginWithPhoneNumber({
    useAccessToken: true,
    defaultCountryCode: "US",
  },function(res){
    console.log(res)
  },function(err){
     console.log(err)
})
```

Reference: https://codesundar.com/ionic-accountkit-integration/

Comment: i followed your instructions as it is but im facing issue it is displaying as "A system issue occurred please try again"

Comment: Are you getting SMS ?

Comment: it is asking phonenumber after entering the phone number it is displaying A system issue occuured message

Comment: Make sure, you have valid client tokens,& other details; Turn on your facebook app to live mode. I faced same issue, but resolved by these steps; Also console error callback; If not, just create a blank new project & try from beginning

Comment: do we have to mention these in config.xml do we have to mention these in config.xml                                       
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: Yes, but you have to add inside AndroidManifest.xml (platforms/andriod)